# Better format for byebug (with colors)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, byebug

Is there a way to get a better format of output with byebug? When I print objects the output is a little hard to read, would be better with colors similar to `Awesome Print`.

Comment: Use your pp. Try `require "pp"` and when inspecting objects use `pp object`.

Comment: ...or just use awesome_print?

Comment: Pry has been super helpful, but that's more about line formatting than color.

Answer (score 5):

There is no native option on byebug to format the output with colors, but there is a Gem you can use to colorize some of byebug output for ease of readability, which I think is what you are aiming here.

Please follow this link to see instructions on how to install byebug-color-printer Gem. 
https://github.com/ahmadsherif/byebug-color-printer

Or you could use pry. https://github.com/pry/pry :)

Let me know how this works for you. I hope it helps.

Comment: byebug-color-printer won't work unless you want to use a very old version of byebug: https://github.com/ahmadsherif/byebug-color-printer/blob/master/byebug-color-printer.gemspec#L21

Answer (score 3):

I am using a hack for **byebug syntax highlighting** from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/marian13/5dade20a431d7254db30e543167058ce) for more than a year now.

It is not perfect, but it does its job well.

Here is an example:

[image]

**Note:** It works for byebug v10.0.0 and higher.

**Sources:**

- [Byebug syntax highlighting](https://gist.github.com/marian13/5dade20a431d7254db30e543167058ce).

Comment: What's the not perfect thing about it?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `awesome_print` to your project (via the Gemfile if you use bundler), then ap will be available to you inside `byebug`.

Answer (score 1):

### debug.rb (aka binding.break)

Consider using a new Ruby debugging tool called [debug.rb](https://github.com/ruby/debug).

It supports syntax highlighting and many more out-of-the-box.

Also, it is worth mentioning that it is developed by the Ruby core team.

Just place `binding.break` anywhere in your codebase.

Here is an example:

[image: binding.break example]

Also, it is a [default Rails debugger starting from version 7](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43187).

**Notes:**

- Do not forget about `require 'debug'`
- `q    # quit command`

**Sources:**

- [debug.rb](https://github.com/ruby/debug)
- [Modify source code with binding.break (similar to binding.pry or binding.irb)](https://github.com/ruby/debug#modify-source-code-with-bindingbreak-similar-to-bindingpry-or-bindingirb)
- [Rails 7 replaced byebug with ruby/debug](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/09/29/rails-7-ruby-debug-replaces-byebug.html)
- [Depend on ruby/debug, replacing Byebug](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43187)